# Laravel query builder `SELECT (x IN (?)) AS y`

Tags: laravel, query-builder

How do I make this kind of SELECT with Laravel's query builder:

```
SELECT *, (sector1 IN (...)) AS s1, (sector2 IN (...)) AS s2, (sector3 IN (...)) AS s3
FROM jobs
WHERE (sector1 IN (1, 2) OR sector3 IN (1, 2) OR sector3 IN (1, 2))
ORDER BY (s1 AND s2 AND s3) DESC, (s1 AND s2) DESC, (s1 AND s3) DESC, etc...
```

The `WHERE` part is easy with `whereIn()`, and the `ORDER` part is easy with `orderByRaw()`, but how do I make the `SELECT`?

The results `s1`, `s2` and `s3` can now be used for sorting: first if all 3 sectors match, than if sectors 1 and 2 match, than if sectors 1 and 3 match, etc.

The `(...)` are 1 or more sectors from user input. They must be escaped and inserted etc, like a `WHERE sector1 IN (...)` would.

But how?

`selectRaw` only helps a little, because it doesn't expand an array into multiple placeholders. This is what I have now, but that can't be it:

```
$query->selectRaw("sector1 IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($filters['sectors']), '?'))  . ") AS s1", $filters['sectors']);
```

I have to expand the placeholders myself? There must be a way to let the query builder do that. Maybe an `ConditionExpression` I can't find? The builder itself doesn't seem to have a way to expand `?`, only the Grammar does that when executing the query, which is why `whereIn`/`whereNotIn` etc are all explicit methods.

Comment: What sort of select statement is that supposed to represent?  Typically `IN (...)` should only ever appear in the `WHERE` clause.  Please post your original raw MySQL query to get best results here.

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to be. You can IN anywhere. You can SELECT it, or GROUP BY it, or ORDER BY it, and of course WHERE it. I want to SELECT it, so I can order by 3 of them. I've updated the query, but it won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

`whereIn()` internally uses `Grammar::parameterize()` to expand the placeholders.

You can also use it separately:

```php
$grammar = new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar();
$query->selectRaw("sector1 IN (" . $grammar->parameterize($filters['sectors'])  . ") AS s1", $filters['sectors']);
```

Comment: I know, but that can't be how Laravel works... I like my way (expanding `?` manually) better. But I like neither. Time for a PR I guess.